# Assign variable inside puppet class

Tags: puppet, erb

I'm new to puppet so any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to pass static data into variable `apache_version` inside Puppet class depending on OS release version. This variable will be later used in `.erb` template file to configure apache according to version. For now my class looks like this:

```
class some_class_name () {
  case $::operatingsystem {
    'RedHat' : {
      case $::operatingsystemrelease {
        /^7\..*/ : { }
        /^6\..*/ : { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I define inside `{}` brackets this variable? As for `.erb` file it should be used like this:

```
<%- if @apache_version >= '2.4' -%>
    set something
<%- else -%>
     set something else
<%- end -%>
```

I was aiming for something like this:

```
class some_class_name () {
  case $::operatingsystem {
    'RedHat' : {
      case $::operatingsystemrelease {
        /^7\..*/ : { $apache_version = '2.4' }
        /^6\..*/ : { $apache_version = '2.2' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine for me. What does `facter operatingsystem` and `facter operatingsystemrelease` output exactly? Are you including `some_class_name`? How are you checking the value of `$apache_version`? Add `notify { "Version: ${apache_version}": }` perhaps.

Comment: `facter operatingsystem` gives `RedHat`
`facter operatingsystemrelease` gives `7.2` (at least on system I'm working right now)
`some_class_name` is included in `init.pp` file correctly.

As for checking - I'm not checking it anywhere. Should I? Shouldn't it work like this, that once I assign version to variable it should be used in `.rb` file?

Comment: The variable can be used in the ERB template if the `template()` call is in the same scope, but the manifest shown doesn't have a template() call so it's hard to say whether this is correct.

Comment: FYI there is no reason to end a regular expression with `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve the issue. Now I'm using:

```
if $::operatingsystemrelease =~ /^7\..*/ {
    $apache_version = '2.4'
  } else {
    $apache_version = '2.2'
  }
```

in `params.pp` file. With this everything is being configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `$::operatingsystemmajrelease` fact here:

```
  if $::operatingsystemmajrelease == 7 {
    $apache_version = '2.4'
  } else {
    $apache_version = '2.2'
  }
```

I also think this is a good use-case for Puppet's selector:

```
$apache_version = $::operatingsystemmajrelease ? { 7 => '2.4', default => '2.2' }
```